# How to query data from two tables from mysql database and display one HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables... Only $sql is executing. How do I get $sql2 to query also? $sql2 is storing the secondID with the current_timestamp in the database but not receiving any input from 'serialnumber.' Only the first $sql is querying and storing in the database.

```
       +--------------+
       | SafetyAtt    |       
       +--------------+             
       | SecondID    |
       | SerialNumber |
       +--------------+                    

          +---------+
          | Safety  |
          +---------+
          | ID      |
          | DateLog |
          | Topic   |
          +---------+

      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr align="left">
          <th>Seq</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Topic</th>
          <th># of Attendees</th>
          <th>Add Attendee</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

    <?php
  $sql = "SELECT ID, DateLog, Topic FROM Safety";
  $sql2 = "SELECT secondID, SerialNumber FROM SafetyAtt";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if (!$result) {
    trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);
  }

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td><td>" . $row["DateLog"] . "</td><td>"
    . $row["Topic"] . "</td><td>" . $row["secondID"] . "</td><td>"  ?>
      Serial Number: <input type="text" name="serialnumber" placeholder="Enter serial #"> <?php " . </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
  } else {
   echo "0 results"; 
   }
  $conn->close();
    ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Without seeing your tables, you probably want to create a single query that pulls the related records from both tables using a `JOIN` statement. How do you know which row in the first table should be displayed with which row in the second one?

Comment: Your code never executes `$sql2`

Comment: make a $result2 for $sql2, and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to JOIN your two tables and it should have one query. First you select the columns you want to get, then join the tables by using the foreign key or something else that is common in the two tables. For example,

```
"SELECT car.id, driver.name, driver.age FROM car INNER JOIN driver ON car.driverID=driver.driverID"
```

see this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to more about SQL JOINS.